# Относительное слово

Tags: лингвистика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое "Относительное слово" в русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы спросили, что такое союзные слова, вышеприведенный текст так же можно было бы привести в качестве ответа. Не вижу разницы между союзными словами и относительными словами. И не могу представить, какие еще союзные слова бывают.

Вот.Нашла этот текст и прошла по ссылке на союзные слова.

*СОЮЗНЫЕ СЛОВА. В широком смысле С. С. — слова, обозначающие связь между однородными членами предложения и между целыми предложениями; в этом смысле С. С. делятся на 1. союзы (см.) и 2. относительные слова (см.). Но обыкновенно термин С. С. употребляется в более узком смысле, применяясь только к относительным словам и являясь т. о. тожественным с этим последним.*

Т.е. союз - служебная часть речи. Союзные слова - это относительные местоимения и местоименные наречия, которые служат для связи придаточного с главным, этим они похожи на подчинительные союзы, поэтому и называются союзными словами. Относительные слова - это и есть относительные местоимения и местоименные наречия.

Comment: Ну вообще-то согласно "вышеприведенному тексту" относительные слова являются подмножеством (гипонимом) союзных.

Answer (score 0):

ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫЕ СЛОВА. Такие союзные слова (см.), которые указывают на то, что предложение, в котором они находятся, стоит в том или другом отношении к существительному, входящему в другое предложение, и в то же время сами стоят в известном отношении к другим словам того предложения, в состав которого они входят. О. С. делятся на 1. О. местоимения, т.-е. склоняемые О. С., и 2. О. наречия, т.-е. несклоняемые О. С. Первые употребляются в том предложении, в состав которого входят, в роли существительных (таковы: который, кто, что, какой) или прилагательных (чей), т.-е. имеют падежные формы или формы согласования в роде, числе и падеже, обозначающие те отношения, какие вообще обозначаются падежными формами существительных и формами согласования прилагательных, вторые — в роли наречий, указывая место или время действия глагола, как обозначенное существительным другого предложения. При этом О. местоимения, употребляющиеся в роли существительных, имеют ту особенность, что согласуются в роде и числе (кроме кто и что, различающихся впрочем тем, что указывают на отношение первое — к существительным одушевленного, а второе — неодушевленного рода) с существительным другого предложения, в то время, как падежная форма таких местоимений указывает на отношение их к другим словам того же предложения. Примеры: дорога, по которой мы ехали, шла лесом; это всё, чего я искал; я тот, кого никто не любит; ты знаешь край, где все обильем дышит; это было в тот самый день, когда я родился.
Н. Д. Литературная энциклопедия: Словарь литературных терминов: В 2-х т. / Под редакцией Н. Бродского, А. Лаврецкого, Э. Лунина, В. Львова-Рогачевского, М. Розанова, В. Чешихина-Ветринского. — М.; Л.: Изд-во Л. Д. Френкель, 1925

(Литературная энциклопедия на Академике)